# Is there native function to print a character array in a quoted form?

Tags: c, printf

The following function implements a way to print a character array in a quoted form.

https://github.com/antirez/sds

```
...
s2 = sdscatrepr(s2,s1,sdslen(s1));
printf("%s\n", s2);

output> "a\x01\x02\n"
```

But it depends on an external library. Is there a native C function for the same purpose?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: All c functions are in libraries. The printf function is in the stdio library. Stdio is one of the standard c libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a native C function for the same purpose?

No, there is not.

The code in reference is not as simple as it should be. It implements a more general task. To print a character in readable form use this:

```
int print_char(unsigned char c) {
    switch (c) {
      case '\\': return printf("\\\\");
      case '"':  return printf("\\\"");
      case '\n': return printf("\\n");
      case '\r': return printf("\\r");
      case '\t': return printf("\\t");
      case '\f': return printf("\\f");
      case '\a': return printf("\\a");
      case '\b': return printf("\\b");
      default:
        if (isprint(c))
            return printf("%c", c);
        else
            return printf("\\x%02x", c);
    }
}

int print_string(const char *s, size_t len) {
    int res = printf("\"");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        res += print_char(s[i]);
    }
    return res + printf("\"");
}
```